# My dataframe column output NaN for all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
41-45          93
46-50          81
36-40          73
51-55          71
26-30          67
21-25          62
31-35          61
56-70          29
56-60          26
61 or older    23
15-20          10
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

```
pd.to_numeric(combined['age'], errors='coerce')
```

i used this above code to convert my dataframe column to numeric but all it does it convert it all to NaN values

Here is my output

```
3     NaN
5     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
11    NaN
       ..
696   NaN
697   NaN
698   NaN
699   NaN
701   NaN
Name: age, Length: 651, dtype: float64
```

Comment: what is the output of `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: ```'age': {3: '36-40', 5: '41-45', 8: '31-35', 9: '46-50', 11: '31-35'},```

Comment: Thank you,i just learn from you how to format my questions properly

Comment: numbers like `46-50` are stored as strings as there is no number to reflect them, so pd.to_numeric causes `NaN`.
you have to split column into 2 using delimter and convert later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"age": ["41-45", "46-50","61 or older"], "Col2": [93, 81, 23]})

Cols = ["Lower_End_Age", "Higher_End_Age",] # list of column names for later

# replacing whitespace by delimiter and splitting only once `n=1` using the same delimiter 
df[Cols] = df["age"].str.replace(' ', '-').str.split("-", n=1, expand = True) 

print(df)
           age  Col2 Lower_End_Age Higher_End_Age
0        41-45    93            41             45
1        46-50    81            46             50
2  61 or older    23            61       or-older
```

later:

```
df['Lower_End_Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Lower_End_Age'], errors='coerce')

df.dtypes

age               object
Col2               int64
Lower_End_Age      int64
Higher_End_Age    object
```

and if you want to get rid of `or-older`, simply repeat

```
df['Higher_End_Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Higher_End_Age'], errors='coerce')

print(df)
           age  Col2  Lower_End_Age  Higher_End_Age
0        41-45    93             41            45.0
1        46-50    81             46            50.0
2  61 or older    23             61             NaN
```

Comment: hello, i encounter this error while trying to call my function after doing the above   In [64], in `age_buckets(y)
      1 def age_buckets(y): 
       ----> 2     x = int(y)
      4     if x < 30: 
      5         return '18-29' `

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '41-45'